# Multiprocessing or os.fork, os.exec?

Tags: python

I am using multiprocessing module to fork child processes. Since on forking, child process gets the address space of parent process, I am getting the same logger for parent and child. I want to clear the address space of child process for any values carried over from parent. I got to know that multiprocessing does fork() at lower level but not exec(). I want to know whether it is good to use multiprocessing in my situation or should I go for os.fork() and os.exec() combination or is there any other solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Since `multiprocessing` is running a function from your program as if it were a thread function, it definitely needs a full copy of your process' state. That means doing `fork()`.

Using a higher-level interface provided by `multiprocessing` is generally better. At least you should not care about the `fork()` return code yourself.

`os.fork()` is a lower level function providing less service out-of-the-box, though you certainly can use it for anything `multiprocessing` is used for... at the cost of partial reimplementation of `multiprocessing` code. So, I think, `multiprocessing` should be ok for you.

However, if you process' memory footprint is too large to duplicate it (or if you have other reasons to avoid forking -- open connections to databases, open log files etc.), you may have to make the function you want to run in a new process a separate python program. Then you can run it using `subprocess`, pass parameters to its `stdin`, capture its `stdout` and parse the output to get results.

**UPD:** `os.exec...` [family of functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execl) is hard to use for most of purposes since it replaces your process with a spawned one (if you run the same program as is running, it will restart from the very beginning, not keeping any in-memory data). However, if you really do not need to continue parent process execution, `exec()` may be of some use.

From my personal experience: `os.fork()` is used very often to create daemon processes on Unix; I often use `subprocess` (the communication is through stdin/stdout); almost never used multiprocessing; not a single time in my life I needed `os.exec...()`.

Comment: +1 also, if you don't want to reuse objects from your parent, just create new ones. Overwrite the references if you want to feel safe :)

Answer (score 3):

You can just rebind the logger in the child process to its own. I don't know about other OS, but on Linux the forking doesn't duplicate the entire memory footprint (as Ellioh mentioned), but uses "copy-on-write" concept. So until you change something in the child process - it stays in the memory scope of the parent process. For instance, you can fork 100 child processes (that don't write into memory, only read) and check the overall memory usage. It'll not be `parent_memory_usage * 100`, but much less.